# Encoding issue while using Microsoft document (.doc) format

Tags: python, xml, encoding, docx, doc

I am facing encoding issue in python. I do the following things in order

1. I convert  .doc  format to .docx format
2. I convert .docx to   XML  using unzip
3. I parse the resulting  XML using regular expression. 
   I print the contents into  a Pandas dataframe .

When I print, the contents of the dataframe to a csv file, I see some strange characters like `'rectangular box'`. In the raw file, I see character `'\uFOB3'`.

How can I solve this ?

I work in Ubuntu 16.04 OS with python 3.

```
# 1 convert doc to docx & save the file in DOCXFILENAME  
if filename.endswith('.doc'):
    subprocess.call(['soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'docx', filename])

# 2 Unzip the DOCX file TO its xml contents. Rename 'document.xml' to XMLFILENAME.
subprocess.call(['unzip','-o',DOCXFILENAME,'-d','.'])   

# 3 Convert XML to string for using in regular expression
xmlf = xml.dom.minidom.parse(XMLFILENAME)
xml_string = xmlf.toprettyxml()
```

I use `xml_string` for further processing using regex.

Comment: The XML file that results in Step 2 above is 'utf-8' encoded , as it appears in its header : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: I'd bet your locale settings aren't UTF8. DOCX files are UTF8. If you use a single-byte codepage to display the XML contents you'll end up with boxes or worse, question marks, for any character except the US-ASCII ones.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why don't you use python-docx or a similar library? A `docx` is a package that contains more than one XML files. Some of them contain sytles, some contain common strings. The contents aren't plain-old XML either, they define paragraphs, runs, tables etc

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis for responding. Python3, by default, supports UTF-8. So, that answers your 1st Q. Regarding 2nd, what I am doing is, to track the changes in the document (MS Word .doc) and print them in a tabular format (via a dataframe).

Comment: What *are* you trying to do? If you want to extract data from a *doc* document you should probably use pandoc, not install LibreOffice, convert and then try to deal with the XML files. Even with Libre, why not convert to a text format directly?

Comment: Suppose, a user has done some changes to a word file and saved them in 'Track Changes Enabled' mode. I want to extract these changes, i.e. what text was deleted/inserted  , under what Section etc. So that sums up my problem statement.

Comment: `doc` is obsolete anyway and even online services like Google Docs or Office Online only support it with paid subscriptions. Anyone that produces a `doc` can just as easily produce a `docx` with any Word version from 2006 and later. Tell your users to stop storing documents in compatiblity mode and ignoring Word's own warnings for starters

Comment: Well, I used XML because when I tried to convert to html ,the changes information was not captured in the resulting html file ( I tried many utilities for that).

Comment: The documents that I have are only in .doc format and that cannot be changed since its user proprietary data.

Comment: I did not get ur 2nd point i.e directly converting to text. If I do that, I loose what word/line/character was deleted/inserted. I have to extract that.